# Здравствуйте недавно начал стал учить Java можете помочь что здесь неправильно

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte num = 23;
        System.out.print(num);

    }
```

выдает такую ошибку:

```
  cod.java:9: error: reached end of file while parsing
    }
     ^
1 error
```

Comment: посчитайте количество открывающих и закрывающих скобок

Comment: Мне кажется таким вопросам не место на SO.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте в конце, закрывающую класс Main, скобку.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte num = 23;
        System.out.print(num);

    }
}
```